# How does gearing affect top speed and acceleration exactly

Tags: gears, power-transmission, acceleration

I was just reading an article about "What affects a car's overall top speed" and it left me wondering how gearing affects top speed and acceleration. While I did manage to learn how everything else affects top speed, this particular factor just left me a little confused. Here's an example: Car A can reach 60 mph in 2.5 seconds and reach a speed of 170 mph with 590 hp. Car B can reach 60 mph in 3.3 seconds and reach a speed of 175 hp with 620 hp. Does this indicate anything? When I look up a particular car, they don't really mention anything related about the car's gearing.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the engine power needs to overcome two forces.

One is down to the rolling friction losses and the other is down to aerodynamics.

The aerodynamic forces are greater than the rolling friction losses after about 40mph.

The aerodynamic forces increase based on the velocity cubed so as you go faster you need even more power.

Think of it this way: the faster you move the more air you have to push out of the way. This is why the faster cars have « slippery » shapes.

So just changing the gearing may not increase a car’s top speed, in fact even changing tire size can cause the top speed to be reduced…

Answer (score 0):

Infinite torque gives you infinite acceleration, but even then you can never go faster than the speed your wheels spin at and distance traveled per wheel revolution as determined by diameter.

Torque combined with wheel diameter determines the force at the edge of the wheel. This is required to get up to speed faster, but you also need it to overcome drag and other losses.

If you don't have enough force at the edge of the wheel, one of two things happens:

1. you either take too long to get up to speed before you need to turn
   or stop that it doesn't matter that the fact your wheels can *eventually* spin really fast under load
2. Don't have enough force behind the wheels to over come drag and friction to get the wheels spinning that fast under load, even if the  wheels can spin that fast under no load (i.e. when lifted off the ground.)

Gearing determines the allocation of engine power to wheel RPM and torque. You need the correct balance of gearing to allocate engine power appropriately between torque and RPM because there are diminishing returns and opportunity cost.

You might have already gathered that wheel diameter is also a form of gearing and works with the transmission gearing. Larger diameter = less force at the edge of the wheel for a given torque at the hub but higher circumferential/linear distance traveled for a given rotation (higher linear velocity per RPM).

They don't mention gearing because it is irrelevant for an end user and pointless without taking the engine, weight, and payload into account (another can of worms). It's a bunch of numbers balanced against each other and graphs which is too much to take in. Consider the fact that you got confused and had to ask what the effect of gearing is. That's an indication that even the high-level concepts are not obvious to most people, let alone actually understanding it well enough to compare cars. That's why it's not listed.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO the main reason that the gearbox setting is sparsely mentioned in car specs is that it is not one a marketing point. The gearbox ratios are about optimisation and working in harmony with the other components, while the engine specs (power and torque) can be more easily utilised in testosterone driven comparisons.

The following is an --almost word for word-- excerpt from my answer to the question "What affects a car's overall top speed", which I think is relevant.

---

### Gearbox

Although, theoretically the top speed is determined by power and aerodynamic drag, the gearbox plays an important role. First of all, (my pardon for being so pedantically detailed), the gearbox determines the compromise between the acceleration and top speed.

For simplicity purposes I will consider the differential as part of the gear box (so I will consider the ratio of the entire drivetrain). I will denote the entire drivetrain as $i_d$, and its defined as:

$$i_d = \frac{n_{engine}}{n_{wheels}}$$

To make more clear what I'm saying, is that if in the above example of the car with 150hp at 5500 rpm, the $i_d$ was equal to 1, and the car had a tire diameter of $d_W=0.5m$, then at the max power the speed would have been:

$$u= \frac{2\cdot \pi}{60} \cdot \frac{n_{engine}}{i_d} \frac{d_W}{2}  = 904 \frac{m}{s}$$

so it would be supersonic (speed of sound is 340 m/s). **So why don't we do that?**

The problem is that if the gear ratio is too low, then the torque (and therefore the force applied from the tires is too small). On the other had if the drivetrain ratio is high, then the forces on the tires would be too high (and the tires would lose traction - think accelerating in a manual car to hard in 1st gear).

So there is an optimal compromise, that determines the drivetrain gear ratio.

For example, for Car A (we know the max power of 470hp, and the max speed is 160pmh) if we assume that the max power is reached at 6000 rpm, and the tire diameter is 0.5m, then the overall *theoretically* optimal drivetrain can be calculated to be
$$i_d= \frac{\pi \cdot n_{engine} \cdot d_w}{ u}$$
$$i_d= 13.8$$

---

The bottom line is that different cars have different uses. Therefore their "trimming" needs to be slightly different. For a given car power, obtaining top speed and top acceleration requires different paths for the drivetrain. The gearbox (and in most cases the differential), offers a quick way to trim the performance of the car at the optimal compromise (-- this is subjective to the race engineer's judgement--) between top speed or acceleration.

Answer (score 0):

All engines have a different sweet zone in the combination of RPM and Torque and power demand. Usually, the engine output should be slightly ahead of power demand on the torque versus RPM curve.

It was immediately obvious in the old times with manual gearboxes when the engine was choking under the load and we needed to shift the gear low.
Or when the engine was revving fast end moaning for shifting up.

The job of the gear is to always mediate between the engine output and the power demand so that the engine is working within its optimal envelope. As we used to say it has room to breathe.

If you are driving on a steep uphill road power and torque is the key. If you are on a flat open road speed and fuel economy is the key.